# Create TableLayoutPanel programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tablelayoutpanel

I have `TabControl` that contains one `TabPage`, and other TabPages are added dynamically, on event.

First TabPage contains `TableLayoutPanel`, so I am wondering is there any chance to add new `TableLayoutPanel` to every new created `TabPage`, which is same as first `TableLayoutPanel` but empty?

Or, in other words, could I create `TableLayoutPanel` programmatically?

Comment: TLP is a bit painful, it was heavily designed to be easy to use from the designer.  Which does not equate to "easy to use" in your own code.  Best way to get the code is to actually use the designer and then look at the form's Designer.cs file for the code.  Copy/paste the important bits of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can create **any** control programmatically, including `TableLayoutPanel`. Actually when you are using designer controls are also created programmatically - code is generated by Visual Studio.

Simply create new `TableLayoutPanel` control and set all it's properties (rows, columns, etc). Then add this control to `Controls` property of new tab page:

```
TabPage page = new TabPage("Another page");
page.Controls.Add(new TableLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill});
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(page);
```

Another option for you is creating [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) with already configured `TableLayoutPanel`. In this case you will need only to create new user control and add it to tab page.

Also you can create custom `TableLayoutPanel` with specified rows, columns and other settings. E.g. this control will have two rows with predefined height of 25% and 75%

```
public class CustomTableLayoutPanel : TableLayoutPanel
{
    public CustomTableLayoutPanel()
    {
        RowStyles.Clear();
        RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0.25F));
        RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0.75F));
        BackColor = Color.Beige;
    }
}
```